# how to find Integral using different lower bounds in R

Tags: r

I have data with two variables. Each variable has 10 observations. I would like to find 10 integral using each observation in variable one as a lower bound. I tried code as follows,

```
   data = data.table(x=x, y=y)
     for(i in 1:n){
     F <- ecdf(data$x)
     f <- function(h){((1-F(h))/(1-F(data[i,1])))^((1-0.1*(theta-lambda))/(0.1*lambda))}
    m_i <-data$x[i]
   data$k <- integrate(f, lower=m_i, upper=1)$value
    }
```

But I got "Error in stats::integrate(...) : non-finite function value", any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: We need to see your data.

Comment: Also `n` is not defined.